# Counting rows in Vertica table per JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset, vertica, rowcount

How can I get the number of lines in a ResultSet, plugged on a Vertica 8 database, knowing every ResultSet is forward only when using Vertica? I'm trying to adapt an existing software, originally developped for Oracle, so if I could find a way to avoid rewritting everything using calls to `SELECT count(*)...` queries, it would really make my life easier...

Comment: In general the number of rows in a result set is not known until the last row is fetched.

Comment: so you wanna know the numbers of rows fetched by each session per each jdbc connection ?

Comment: No, I want to know the number of results returned by a query. Is it unclear in my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I know the Vertica JDCB (see: Vetica doc: JDBC Feature Support):
"Cursors are forward only and are not scrollable. Result sets cannot be updated."

So, you can't get the number of rows until you arrived the end of the ResultSet.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a bit tricky ! Because you mention "JDBC", which point ot the fact that only jdbc connections should be monitored for this !

Now ! in regards to your question and this might not be what you are looking for.

In order for you to know where or from which JDBC connection your query`s come you need to label your JDBC (good practice), this way you can point to your "bad/heavy" users and know to whom you need to explain how Vertica works.

- 1- Label JDBC

[image]

- 2 - Use the **sessions** table to identify from where the connections come from.

SELECT
        ss.session_id,
        qp.query_type,
        qp.processed_row_count,
        qp.user_name
    FROM
        query_profiles qp
    JOIN
        sessions ss
    ON
        ss.session_id=qp.session_id
    WHERE
        ss.client_label=''
    AND qp.error_code IS NULL
    AND qp.is_executing='false'
    ORDER BY
        qp.processed_row_count DESC

*The Column PROCESSED_ROW_COUNT in query_profile shows the number of rows returned by the query.*
[Vertica Doc reference](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/SystemTables/MONITOR/QUERY_PROFILES.html)

I think this is half of the answers but i hope it helped.